# how to spead a list and put into a new column based on number of rows

Tags: python, pandas, list

lets say I have a brand of list:

```
cat_list = ['a', 'b', 'ab']
```

and I want this list to repeteadly fill a new column called `category` as much as my rows have.

I want the first row have `'a'`, the second row have `'b'`, and the third row have `'ab'`, and the cycle repeats until the last rows like the example below:

```
type     value     category
a         25          a
a         25          b
a         25          ab
b         50          a
b         50          b
b         50          ab
```

What I have tried so far is:

```
cat_list = ['a', 'b', 'ab']
df['category'] = cat_list * len(df)
```

but I got this kind of error

```
Length of values does not match length of index
```

how should I fix my script in order to get the desired results?

thanks.

Comment: To be clear: do you mean that every row should have `['a', 'b', 'ab']`? Or do you mean that the first row should have `'a'`, then the second row should have `'b'`, the third row should have `'ab'`, then the cycle repeats until the end? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: yes I mean the second one. The first row should have 'a', the second should have 'b', the third shoul have 'ab', then the cycle repeats until the last row. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.tile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) by repeat with integer division for number of repeats:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(8)})

cat_list = ['a', 'b', 'ab']
df['category'] = np.tile(cat_list, (len(df.index) // len(cat_list)) + 1)[:len(df.index)]
print (df)
   a category
0  0        a
1  1        b
2  2       ab
3  3        a
4  4        b
5  5       ab
6  6        a
7  7        b
```

Comment: Looks good. I assume `[:len(df.index)]` is to handle the cases where the Dataframe length isn't evenly divisible by the source length?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel - exactly you are right.